# Python default parameter if no command line arguments are passed

Tags: python, argparse

I'l like to build a program with this behaviour:

usage: sage 4ct.py [-h] (-r R | -i I | -p P) [-o O]

But if you don't give any parameter, I'd like to have "-r 100" as the default.

Is it possible?

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = '4ct args')

group_input = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required = True)
group_input.add_argument("-r", "-random", help = "Random graph: dual of a triangulation of N vertices", nargs = 1, type = int, default = 100)
group_input.add_argument("-i", "-input", help = "Input edgelist filename (networkx)", nargs = 1)
group_input.add_argument("-p", "-planar", help = "Load a planar embedding of the graph G.faces() - Automatically saved at each run: input_planar_file.serialized", nargs = 1)
parser.add_argument("-o", "-output", help="Output edgelist filename (networkx)", nargs = 1, required = False)

args = parser.parse_args()
```

Comment: Eh? `100` already is the default for `args.random`. Why are you adding a **required** group, if you don't want to require the user to pass a member of it explicitly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove the `required`argument of the `add_mutually_exclusive_group` function call (or set it to False) and you're done:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = '4ct args')

group_input = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required = False)
group_input.add_argument("-r", "--random", help = "Random graph: dual of a triangulation of N vertices", type = int, default = 100)
group_input.add_argument("-i", "--input", help = "Input edgelist filename (networkx)")
group_input.add_argument("-p", "--planar", help = "Load a planar embedding of the graph G.faces() - Automatically saved at each run: input_planar_file.serialized")
parser.add_argument("-o", "--output", help="Output edgelist filename (networkx)", required = False)

print(parser.parse_args())
# Namespace(input=None, output=None, planar=None, random=100)
print(parser.parse_args("-r 77".split()))
# Namespace(input=None, output=None, planar=None, random=77)
print(parser.parse_args("-o some/path".split()))
# Namespace(input=None, output='some/path', planar=None, random=100)
print(parser.parse_args("-i some/path".split()))
# Namespace(input='some/path', output=None, planar=None, random=100)
print(parser.parse_args("-i some/path -o some/other/path".split()))
# Namespace(input='some/path', output='some/other/path', planar=None, random=100)
print(parser.parse_args("-r 42 -o some/other/path".split()))
# Namespace(input=None, output='some/other/path', planar=None, random=42)
```

As you can see, the `random` option is defaulted to 100 even if:

- the `output` option is provided, which seems normal
- an option from the mutual exclusive group other than `random` is provided, which can be problematic. you will have to check in your code if `random` is the only exclusive option which has a value before taking it in account.

---

This example also includes some tiny improvement to your option parser:

- use long option names with two dashes (it is a convention but it also allows argparse to correctly recognise option name).
- remove the `nargs=1` in your options definitions which makes you retrieve a list of one value. By removing it, you could retrieve directly the value.

Comment: The way I understood the OP is that `r=100` is only desired if no arguments are given at all. If I understand your answer correctly r would equal 100 if no r is given.

Comment: @THeeren: The OP question seems to give credit at your version. But it may be a lack of precision; and since this version makes no sense from my point of view, I prefer to give this solution which defaults the `random` value even if the `output` option is provided ;)

Comment: I agree. It seems he requires either one of r/i/p. However, if only -o is given in my answer, no r/i/p will be provided.

Comment: What I needed is that r/i/p is an indipendent group respect to the -o parameter

Comment: Also this one works and seems more in line with the Python library capabilities. Another small question: is it correct to check the "r" parameter with this instruction? if args.r is not None:

Comment: @MarioStefanutti: It is correct if you keep single-dashed long option name. If you use double-dashed long option name, you will have to use `args.random`

Comment: If I don't give parameters and I want to use the default, I don't know if I have to check it with args.r or args.random (the latter worked fine). Next little problem is that now I am not able to get the value: "if agrs.random is not None: print ("value: ", args.random[0]) --- Sorry but I'm new with python and the arg lib

Comment: @MarioStefanutti: The answer is already in my answer. By removing the `nargs=1` argument in the options declarations, you no longer retrieve a list, but a single value. So you have to access the value by `args.random` instead of `args.random[0]`. This is the same for all other options.

Answer (score 1):

Give the following a try:

```
import argparse
import sys

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='4ct args')

group_input = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
group_input.add_argument("-r", "-random", help="Random graph: dual of a triangulation of N vertices", nargs=1, type=int,             default=100)
group_input.add_argument("-i", "-input", help="Input edgelist filename (networkx)", nargs=1)
group_input.add_argument("-p", "-planar", help="Load a planar embedding of the graph G.faces() - Automatically saved at each run: input_planar_file.serialized",nargs=1)
parser.add_argument("-o", "-output", help="Output edgelist filename (networkx)", nargs=1, required=False)

if not sys.argv[1:]:
    sys.argv.extend(['-r', '100'])

args = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
```

Essentially you are checking  if any commandline parameters are given at all, and if not, you append the desired `-r 100`